# std::unique pointer and custom lambda deleter error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, lambda, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I am trying to use a std::unique_pointer and supply a custom lambda deleter with it, but I am getting syntax error:

```
cannot convert from 'wmain::<lambda_0f8f736f48c52ca6fa24492e7c0c1ec0>' to 'const std::default_delete<_Ty>'
```

with the following simple, minimal code:

```
#include <memory>

class TestClass
{
};

typedef std::unique_ptr<TestClass> TestClassPtr;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    TestClassPtr testPtr(new TestClass(), [](TestClass* w){ delete w;});

    return 0;
}
```

Is this the wrong way to supply a lambda deleter to a smart pointer?

Comment: Just so we're clear, this is literally what `std::default_deleter<T>` does, so you're really not doing anything meaningful even if it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The deleter must be part of the `unique_ptr`'s type.

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<TestClass, void(*)(TestClass *)> TestClassPtr;
```

Your code should work after you make this change. Also, I'm assuming you're going to do something other than simply call `delete` on the pointer within the deleter. If not, there's no need to supply a custom deleter.

Comment: [Could also do this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=5c1496ef39030f333dd4a8e6d5161aae-ad01b9d4245b5d59a84467091ae99245). However every lambda has its own type even if they're exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Yes I was just supplying a minimal example to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0):

No need to use a type definition or to save the lambda in an automatic variable.  In the code that follows, ignore the highlighting of Type.  This code is pseudo-code made from code in one of my working applications.

In the hpp class declaration:

The in class initialization is ugly but mandatory.  Haven't tried C++14 std::make_unique() on the right of the assignment.  C++11 was all there was at the time I wrote this.

```
std::unique_ptr<Type, rtype (*)(Type*)> member = std::unique_ptr<Type, rtype (*)(Type*)>(nullptr, nullptr);
```

In the .cpp class definition:

```
member = std::unique_ptr<Type, rtype (*)(Type*)>(new Type(), [](Type* ptr2_Type) {
    delete ptr2_Type;
    return rtype;
});
```

For static members, follow the rules for static members: no in class initialization.  Initialize outside of any function in the cpp file using the fully qualified name.

Tip: Stick to initializing to null pointer and assigning true values later if things mysteriously fail to work doing otherwise.